# Serving Static Images from Application in Django

Tags: python, django

I am following a Django book which builds a web application. When I build a template, I get the same result as that of the book, except for my images - they are not there.

I am wondering what can be causing this issue. The images have correct URL's but when I try to open them, Django states "Page NOT found 404".

I am pasting the relevant code below. In addition, I include a screenshot of my directory tree.

[image]

shop/models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

template:

```
<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="  {% if product.image %}
                                {{ product.image.url }}
                            {%else %}
                                {% static 'img/no_image.png' %}
                            {% endif %}
                ">
           </a>
```

views.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html',
                            {'category': category,
                            'categories': categories,
                            'products': products})
```

**Edit (settings.py and urls.py):**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
    url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                             document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you share your `settings.py` and project `urls.py`?

Comment: What are the values of MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py file?

Comment: I have edits to include those.

Comment: Shouldn't your media dir be in root folder? try moving to the root from app folder

Comment: Also, it looks like I was able to fix it after re-creating the products and adding the same exact images to them. I am not sure why the problem existed in the first place.